# How to set multiple bit values within an integer

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation, arrays, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am coding a program in vb.net using Visual Studio 2015.  I am trying to figure out how to modify individual bits in a 16 bit integer.  The numeric data-type byte-order is little-Indian and is as follows:

- origin (2 bits)
- tagged (1 bit)
- addressable (1 bit)
- protocol (12 bits)

> ```
> Field:  [ origin ] [tagged] [addressable] [protocol]
> Bits:    16 15      14       13            12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
> ```

In the example code below, I am trying to figure out how to set origin, tagged, addressable and protocol in the variable "i" which is a 16 bit integer.

```
  Dim i As UInt16 = 0
  Dim origin As Byte = 0          ' Message origin indicator
  Dim tagged As Byte = 0          ' Determines usage of the Frame Address target field (0 or 1)
  Dim addressable As Byte = 0     ' Message includes a target address (0 or 1)
  Dim protocol As UInt16 = 1024   ' Protocol number: must be 1024 (decimal)
```

Can anyone provide a vb.net example of how I can update the variable "i" so that it contains the bit values for origin, tagged, addressable and protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `or` to set individual bits and `>>` and `<<` to shift bits.

For example, to set two bytes from tagged, addressable and protocol, you can do:

```
Dim tagged As Byte = 1          ' Determines usage of the Frame Address target field (0 or 1)
Dim addressable As Byte = 1     ' Message includes a target address (0 or 1)
Dim protocol As UInt16 = 1026   ' Protocol number: must be 1024 (decimal)

sendbuf(0) = sendbuf(0) or tagged ' bit 0
sendbuf(0) = sendbuf(0) or (addressable << 1) ' bit 1
sendbuf(0) = sendbuf(0) or ((protocol << 2) and 255) ' first 6 bits of protocol

sendbuf(1) = sendbuf(1) or (protocol >> 6) ' next 6 bits of protocol
```

You may need to adjust it - I didn't follow the link, so I'm not completely sure which bits should go where (there's 14 bits to fit into 2 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Map the bit values using binary values in an enumeration. 1 = 1, 2 = 10, 4 = 100, etc. Then you can assign your variable using the enumeration. You can also combine the values into a new enumeration (see ProtocolX).

To give initial values, just add the enumeration you want to use.

```
    ' switch bits on 1, 5, 13, 14, 16
    i = FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit1 + FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit5 +
        FrameSectionEnum.AddressableBit13 +
        FrameSectionEnum.TaggedBit14 + FrameSectionEnum.OriginBit16
    PrintBits(i)
```

To switch on some bits and preserve the other bits, use OR.

```
    ' switch bits on 2 and 3 using a combined value. preserve other bits
    i = SetOn(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolX)
    PrintBits(i)
```

To switch off some bits and preserve the other bits, use AND and NOT.

```
    ' switch bits off 1 and 5
    i = SetOff(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit1 + FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit5)
    PrintBits(i)
```

### List of utilities functions:

Check if certain bits is on:

```
Function CheckBit(i As Integer, bit As FrameSectionEnum) As Integer
    Return If((i And bit) = bit, 1, 0)
End Function
```

Set bits on, preserve other bits:

```
Function SetOn(i As Integer, bit As FrameSectionEnum) As Integer
    Return i Or bit
End Function
```

Set bits off, preserve other bits:

```
Function SetOff(i As Integer, bit As FrameSectionEnum) As Integer
    Return i And (Not bit)
End Function
```

### Full code:

```
Module Module1

    Enum FrameSectionEnum
        ProtocolBit1 = 1
        ProtocolBit2 = 2
        ProtocolBit3 = 4
        ProtocolBit4 = 8
        ProtocolBit5 = 16
        ProtocolBit6 = 32
        ProtocolBit7 = 64
        ProtocolBit8 = 128
        ProtocolBit9 = 256
        ProtocolBit10 = 512
        ProtocolBit11 = 1024
        ProtocolBit12 = 2048

        AddressableBit13 = 4096

        TaggedBit14 = 8192

        OriginBit15 = 16384
        OriginBit16 = 32768

        ProtocolX = ProtocolBit2 + ProtocolBit3
    End Enum


    Sub Main()

        Dim i As UInt16 = 0
        ' switch bits on 1, 5, 13, 14, 16
        i = FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit1 + FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit5 +
            FrameSectionEnum.AddressableBit13 +
            FrameSectionEnum.TaggedBit14 + FrameSectionEnum.OriginBit16
        PrintBits(i)

        ' switch bits on 2 and 3 using a combined value. preserve other bits
        i = SetOn(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolX)
        PrintBits(i)

        ' switch bits off 1 and 5
        i = SetOff(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit1 + FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit5)
        PrintBits(i)

        Console.ReadKey(True)

    End Sub

    Function SetOn(i As Integer, bit As FrameSectionEnum) As Integer
        Return i Or bit
    End Function

    Function SetOff(i As Integer, bit As FrameSectionEnum) As Integer
        Return i And (Not bit)
    End Function

    Function CheckBit(i As Integer, bit As FrameSectionEnum) As Integer
        Return If((i And bit) = bit, 1, 0)
    End Function

    Sub PrintBits(i As Integer)

        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.OriginBit16))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.OriginBit15))

        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.TaggedBit14))

        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.AddressableBit13))

        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit12))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit11))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit10))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit9))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit8))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit7))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit6))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit5))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit4))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit3))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit2))
        Console.Write(CheckBit(i, FrameSectionEnum.ProtocolBit1))

        Console.WriteLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

The header format in the question contains the key to getting all the bits in the right place. For me personally, it's easier to visualize if you renumber the bits using a zero-based index:

> ```
> Field:  [ origin ] [tagged] [addressable] [protocol]
> Bits:    15 14      13       12            11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
> ```

Starting with the `origin` field, it needs to be shifted 14 bits to the left, which can be done like this:

```
origin << 14
```

The `tagged` and `addressable` fields need to be shifted to the left by 13 and 12 bits, respectively, which can be done the same way. The `protocol` field is already in the right place, so it doesn't need to be shifted. They can all be combined together with the `Or` operator as follows:

```
i = (origin << 14) Or (tagged << 13) Or (addressable << 12) Or protocol
```

One last detail that needs to be addressed is that in VB.NET, bit shift operations are dependent upon the datatype that is being shifted. In your code above, the `origin`, `tagged`, and `addressable` variables are all of type `Byte`. Shifts on this type will all be done modulo 8 (the number of bits in a byte), meaning a shift of 9 bits is the same of a shift of 1 bit.

Because all of our shifts are more than 8 bits, we need to convert to a wider datatype or else things won't end up in the right place. The easy way to do this is to just change the declarations of all the variables to `UInt16`:

```
Dim i As UInt16
Dim origin As UInt16 = 0
Dim tagged As UInt16 = 0
Dim addressable As UInt16 = 0
Dim protocol As UInt16 = 1024

i = (origin << 14) Or (tagged << 13) Or (addressable << 12) Or protocol
```

The alternative to this is to keep your variables declared as they are and use `CType` to convert the fields right before doing the shifts:

```
Dim i As UInt16 = 0
Dim origin As Byte = 0
Dim tagged As Byte = 0
Dim addressable As Byte = 0
Dim protocol As UInt16 = 1024

i = (CType(origin, UInt16) << 14) Or (CType(tagged, UInt16) << 13) Or (CType(addressable, UInt16) << 12) Or protocol
```

Personally, I prefer the first way due to brevity, but the choice is yours!